# Postgresql: cannot access psql after changing user password

Tags: macos, postgresql, pgadmin

After a few weeks of not using my postgres db, I need to use it again. To my knowledge I haven't changed anything in the configuration since then, but I cannot login as my normal superuser.

```
psql -d %dbname% -U %username%
```

I get: `psql: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "%username%"`

Here's what I've done so far:

Sudo into the db: `sudo -u %OS_username% psql`

Test create a user to verify commands work: `CREATE USER test WITH PASSWORD 'test';` (it worked)

Change my password: `ALTER USER %username% PASSWORD 'test'`

Reboot the server: `pg_ctl restart -D ~/Library/Application\ Support/Postgres/var-9.3`

Then I try `psql -d %dbname% -U %username%` again, but it fails with the same message.

Below are the active connection configurations from my `pg_hba.conf`:

```
local   all             all                                     trust
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
local   all             %username%                              trust
```

I have only added the last line today, and made no other changes. PG Commander/PGAdmin refused to login as normal (as they always have done). Why and where could the credentials have been changed?

Edit: I should also note that I cannot login with the test user I created.

Comment: At a guess you have >1 PostgreSQL instance on your system, and you're not using the same one for everything. It's hard to say when you mask out lots of the details.

Comment: I only have 1 postgreSQL instance on my machine, but a few separate databases. Regardless, the issue mysteriously resolved itself after about a week's time and a few more restarts.